# Get article image according to id php

Tags: php, image, pdo

I'm trying to fetch all articles and images from a database $.
The problem is I couldn't figure out how to get the image according to the article id:

[image]

```
<?php include('navindex.php');?>
    <div class="container">
        <?php 
        include('pdo.php');
        /*
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM annonce WHERE id_annonce =:id";
        $query = $open->prepare($sql);
        */ 

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM annonce WHERE id_annonce=id_annonce";
        //$sql = "SELECT * FROM widgets WHERE something='something else'";
        /*
        foreach ($open->query($sql) as $results)
        {
            $id = $results["id_annonce"];
        }

        */


        //print_r($result);
        ?>
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="image/thumbnail.png">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h3>Titre d'annonce</h3>
                            <p>prix 200</p>
                            <p>surface 400</p>
                        </div>
                        </div>  
                </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <?php include('footer.php'); ?>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Home screen should look like this:

[image]

Comment: where is the attempt to get an image in this?

Comment: @developerwjk i'm trying to output the image according to the article id so every article should have it's own image

Comment: I don't see that in the code is what I meant

Comment: @developerwjk i tried every code sample and i didn't get any solution, i would appreciate your help

Comment: you should post the code where you are trying to do it, rather than the code where you gave up and removed it

Comment: @developerwjk okey i'll edit the post :)